# How to use gdal(geodjango) in aws lambda?

Tags: lambda, postgis, gdal, serverless, geodjango

No matter how hard I looked, I couldn't find a good way.
How to install gdal in aws lambda?
If my question is not enough, please correct me. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option IMO is to use a lambda layer. You can either create one yourself or use one which has been compiled and made available publicly (availability depends on your region).

Here are two options:

https://github.com/lambgeo/docker-lambda
https://github.com/developmentseed/geolambda

For instance, if you want to use the layer from lambgeo in `us-east-1`, you can just add one of these `arn`s to your function:

```
"layers": [
            {
                "name": "gdal24",
                "arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:524387336408:layer:gdal24:1",
                "version": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "gdal30",
                "arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:524387336408:layer:gdal30:1",
                "version": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "gdal31",
                "arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:524387336408:layer:gdal31:1",
                "version": 1
            }
```

For a full list of regions and `arn`s, see [this](https://github.com/lambgeo/docker-lambda/blob/master/arns.json) link.

---

### Additional information

After add layer, should add environment variables to lambda below informations
Here is an example using docker-lambda.

```sh
"GDAL_DATA": "/opt/share/gdal",
"PROJ_LIB": "/opt/share/proj",
"GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/lib/libgdal.so.2.x.x",    // Enter correct version
"GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/lib/libgeos_c.so.1.xx.x"  // Enter correct version
```

For django, edit your django settings.py

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Comment: I just tried developmentseed/geolambda. It is work for small function. but couldn't use with my django project. because it's over 250MB limitation. my django project just 20MB btw.

Comment: are you just using the arn or building the layer yourself? Maybe give docker-lambda a try? Works well for me

Comment: I created the layer myself because I need to run it in the ap-northeast-2 region.

Comment: Oh i found for that region. let me try. but I need python package.

Comment: you should be able to package your code and dependencies as usual ... when you add the layer arn, you'll have gdal available basically just as if you would have packaged it yourself

Comment: It was a matter of how. As you said, just adding gdal arn to the layer solved it. But since it's django, we needed some additional settings. Can I modify the answer a little bit?

Comment: Similarly had an issue with developmentseed's geolambda (the extracted layer was over the limit in size). Is this GDAL lib contains OGR as well?

Comment: Maybe a really dumb question, but how do you figure out which version you have/need to use for libgdal and libgeos ?