# Lambda Layer for GDAL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gdal, aws-lambda-layers, gdal-python-bindings

I am trying to use the GDAL as a lambda layer in my AWS environment. But I am getting this error response:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_gdal' from 'osgeo' (/opt/python/osgeo/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I believe I did not install that GDAL successfully. I just used the "pip install [GDAL Wheel file] -t . " command to install using the wheel file and imported the generated file to my lambda layer.

I did that because I'm having a problem running the command "pip install gdal" it says "Running setup.py install for GDAL did not run successfully."

Now, my question is, is there any way I can import gdal as layer in my AWS environment using python?

Comment: You can use lambda containers and bundle all dependencies that you want in your docker image.

Comment: [This answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505499/5997555) might be helpful